# Is there anything similar to logical AND that can be used in a bash script?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to read from two files at the same time in a bash script? Something similar to usage of & in a programming language example:

```
for i in $(cat filea.txt) & for j in $(cat fileb.txt)
do
    if "$j" = "$i"
    then echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Meaning: I want line 1 of filea to be compared with line 1 of fileb and line2 of filea to be compared with line2 of fileb and so on.

Comment: I don't think there is any such construct.  If there is, it will be highly specific to `bash`.

Comment: I believe you are looking for lock-step iteration in bash

Comment: What is `$cat`? I don't see how the `cat` command could be executed here without backticks `\`cat filea.txt\``. And even that selects words, not lines. (The correction supplied by Jonathan does the same.)

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee: I can't find 'lock-step' or 'lockstep' in the Bash 4.2 reference manual...can you elaborate on what you are talking about?  Is it an actual feature, or 'what would be required'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sounds like he just made that up. But interleaving the two files together might help, if we also have a way to extract lines one at a time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files .

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I made the change because it seemed more like what was being requested.  As originally written `(for i in $cat filea.txt)` would, ignoring the parentheses, have expanded the variable `$cat` and used the words in that plus the name `filea.txt` as the words assigned to `$i`.  In `bash`, you should write `for i in $(<filea.txt)` and not explicitly use `cat`, of course, but that didn't seem as critical to fix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's just the name of iteration type you want, I believe, similar to python and ruby's zip function.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee: Thanks.  As a name, 'lock-step iteration' makes sense and is nicely descriptive, but it sounded like you might be mentioning a feature of `bash`.  It might have misled someone reading the comment into looking for the feature.  If you'd said: "I believe you are looking for 'lock-step iteration' in `bash` like the `zip` function in Python and Ruby." then there would have been no need for a discussion.  Something to keep in mind...not a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do to compare lines, rather than words, is a little contorted, but:

```
while read -r -u 3 line1 && read -r -u 4 line2
do
    if [ "$line1" = "$line2" ]
    then echo "$line2"
    fi
done 3<filea.txt 4<fileb.txt
```

I've explicitly used file descriptors 3 and 4 for symmetry (Polya: "Try to treat symmetrically what is symmetrical, and do not destroy wantonly any natural symmetry”); it would also be possible but less clear to write:

```
while read -r line1 && read -r -u 3 line2
do
    if [ "$line1" = "$line2" ]
    then echo "$line2"
    fi
done <filea.txt 3<fileb.txt
```

---

> What does read -u stand for, and what do 3 and 4 stand for?

Read the Fine Manual — the [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) manual is available online, and if you haven't already got it bookmarked, now would be a fine time to bookmark it.

The `-u`*`fd`* option means 'read from the designated file descriptor (3 or 4 in the example code) instead of from standard input (which is file descriptor 0, of course).  The 3 and 4 stand for the file descriptors to read from.  The code redirects file descriptor 3 from `filea.txt` and file descriptor 4 from `fileb.txt` for the duration of the `while` loop.  Any process that reads file descriptor 3 will get data from `filea.txt`; ditto 4.  The script directs one `read` command to read from 3 and the other from 4, and `read` reads lines, so the net effect is that while there is data available from both `filea.txt` and `fileb.txt`, the loop will run, comparing the two lines and printing.

If your objective is to get the lines that are common between two files printed, then using the `comm` command is much better — see [Jonas Elfström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44620/jonas-elfstrom)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096481/15168) for a good way to do that.

Assuming your objective is to read *lines* from two files in parallel, I can't immediately think of another way to do this in `bash`.  If you need *words* from two files in parallel (which is what the `for i in $(<filea.txt)` notation would give), you'd probably need to use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in conjunction with the I/O redirection:

```
while read -r -u 3 word1 && read -r -u 4 word2
do
    if [ "$word1" = "$word2" ]
    then echo "$word2"
    fi
done 3< <(printf "%s\n" $(<filea.txt)) 4< <(printf "%s\n" $(<fileb.txt))
```

There are other ways to achieve that too, notably using `tr` instead of `printf`, which would be better if the files are big (many megabytes big).

Comment: what does read -u stand for ? and what do 3 and 4 stand for ?

Comment: @user2613272 according to `help read`, `-u` requests a particular file descriptor. 3 and 4 are file descriptors. In the latter example, he's reading from standard input.

Comment: what about the -r by wha way ? what is precisely used for ?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I guess the days are long gone when the `help` command was part of SCCS.

Comment: So you've still not learned how to read the manual, or use the information from `help read` as suggested by Potatoswatter?  `help read` says, in part: _If the `-r` option is given, this signifies `raw' input, and backslash escaping is disabled._  To find out more about what that means, read the manual.

Comment: One last question on this issue : i used this code : while read -r -u 3 line1 && read -r -u 4 line 2 do echo"$line1;$line2" echo "0$line1;$line2" done 3<file1 4<file2   My question is : what if I don't want to use the last 3 lines of file2 at all how can i exclude them ?? thank you

Comment: You turn on the 'prescience' switch so that the program knows when it reaches the last three lines of file 2. :D ... There isn't a particularly easy way to do it, and the solutions are indirect. You arrange to use a program that deletes the last 3 lines from file 2 before feeding it to the `while` loop. That isn't particularly trivial; `sed` doesn't help; neither do `tail` or `head` (that I can see; check GNU `head` which may be able to do it).  I'd be tempted to use `ed file2 <<< '1,$-3p'` but there ought to be a better way. This would use process substitution, too.

Comment: I used your final code but i got /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory and if i try the ordinary one i get invalid file descriptor: bad file number so any suggestions ?

Comment: Which version of `bash`, on which machine type?  Are you using `/bin/sh` and is it actually `bash` or something else?  IIRC, if `bash` is invoked as `sh`, it does not do process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to output the lines that are the same in both files then you can use [comm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html)

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

but if you actually need to step through two files then you can use file descriptors.

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r lineF1 <&3 && read -r lineF2 <&4; do
  echo "$lineF1"
  echo "$lineF2"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Comment: +1 for lateral thinking — though I think it misses the point of the question which is whether there's a way to step through the lines of two files in parallel.

Comment: yes i used it and it worked perfectly; One more question though how can i exclude the last 3 lines of file2 ; i don't want them to be in my output

Comment: This variant will stop when either of the files ends. Are there an equal number of lines in the files?