# merging contents from two files in one file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

File A :

```
1
3
5
7
```

File B:

```
2
4
6
8
```

Is is possible to use File A and File B as input in a shell script and get an output which is File C whose contents are as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interleave lines from two text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `paste` to interleave the lines in the exact order they're found:

```
paste -d '\n' filea fileb
```

Or use `sort` to combine and sort the files:

```
sort filea fileb
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
sort -n FileA FileB > FileC
```

Gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: this does not always work..my filenames are such that sorting it in alphabetical order does not fix it..John Kugelman's method is foolproof..

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the filenames

Comment: `sort -n FileB FileA > FileC` will give the same result.  Though sticking a `-u` in there might also be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat > filea
1
3
5
7
$ cat > fileb
2
4
6
8 
$ sort -m filea fileb
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
$
```

just to make it clear... press ctrl D at the end of each list of numbers for setting up filea and fileb.  Thanks Kevin

Comment: Your first two commands are going to hang forever. You should get rid of the redirect.

Comment: Kevin, yes of course.  There is an invisible ctrl-D happening!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted a shell solution,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
   echo 'usage: interleave filea fileb >out' >&2
   exit 1
fi

exec 3<"$1"
exec 4<"$2"

read -u 3 line_a
ok_a=$?

read -u 4 line_b
ok_b=$?

while [ $ok_a -eq 0 -a $ok_b -eq 0 ] ; do
   echo "$line_a"
   echo "$line_b"

   read -u 3 line_a
   ok_a=$?

   read -u 4 line_b
   ok_b=$?
done

if [ $ok_a -ne 0 -o $ok_b -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo 'Error: Inputs differ in length' >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the second file contents at the end of first file.

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```