# files containing variables shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a script which depends on 3 variables. such as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/sugi/Desktop/rtg-tools-3.5.1/rtg vcfeval -b $1 -c $2 -t /home/sugi/Desktop/hg19.sdf --sample $3 -f AVR -o /home/sugi/Desktop/eval_{$3}
exit
```

I want to execute this script on a list of samples. for that i have 3 files containing the location of the samples and the sample names. for each entry of the files the above command should run. each of the files have the same number of entries per line.

For that I have tried this:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | xargs -i myscript.sh  {} {} {}
```

however this not work. and I have tried several threads also on stackoverflow such as "xargs with multiple arguments. Appreciate any help. Thx.

Comment: Do you want to loop over the lines in the 3 files in parallel?

Comment: use `paste` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files

Comment: @sugsiv What you have does loop over every entry of the files. I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: unfortunately the output is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining paste and xargs:

```
paste file[1-3].txt | xargs -n3 myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If three variables will come from three separate files this should do

```
while read a b c; do ..your_script_here.. done < <(paste file1 file2 file3)
```

refer the variables as $a, $b, $c in the body.