# Place the rows of two blocks of text after each other alternatively

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following two  blocks of text

```
abc
abc
cdz
zer
sdf



bfd
dss
azr
vvf
ezr
```

I want to know how I can place the rows of these two blocks alternatively so that I get the final block of text as following:-

```
abc
bfd
abc
dss
cdz
azr
zer
vvf
sdf
ezr
```

Comment: Isn't there a way in which I can just paste all of the 2nd block rather than doing it one by one? This is because the blocks that I actually have are a lot bigger and it will take a lot of time doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using macro to move 1 line at a time:

1. Start recording macro with your cursor on the 1st char of the 1st line
2. Move cursor down x lines until the first line of the 2nd block (x=8 in this case)

   ```
   8j
   ```
3. Cut this line using `D` instead of `dd` to maintain the distance between the 2 blocks

   ```
   D
   ```
4. Move cursor up x lines to the first line

   ```
   8k
   ```
5. Paste the line we just cut

   ```
   o[esc]p
   ```
6. Move cursor to the next starting position (1st char of the next line)

   ```
   j^
   ```
7. End recording.
8. Replay this macro on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files) question:

1. Write each block to a separate temporary file:

   ```
   vip
   :'<,'>w /tmp/a
   <motion>
   vip
   :'<,'>w /tmp/b
   ```
2. Cut the two blocks.
3. Insert the output of `paste`:

   ```
   :read !paste -d '\n' /tmp/a /tmp/b
   ```